# error retrieving parent:MaterialDrawerTheme

Tags: java, android, string, libraries, material-design

I'm new to android.I wanted to design a material design app and wanted to implement a library but in my string.xml file. I am getting error in this line:

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'MaterialDrawerTheme'.  styles.xml  /SimpleHeaderDrawerActivity/res/values  line 3  Android AAPT Problem`

Anybody please help!
and if anyone can give me a link to show how to implement a library, I'd be glad.

Answer (score 0):

After view your description please check MaterialDrawerTheme style your styles.xml in your value folder properly and check all resource also.

[image]For material drawer please use below tutorial step by step:
https://github.com/ikimuhendis/LDrawer